# Get git to not merge binary files but keep both?

Tags: git, merge, binaryfiles

Currently we commit binary files into source control and these will be changed by different people and then re-committed. However this can produce merge-conflicts.

Realistically as these files contain things like images it doesn't make sense to merge them.

I'm wondering if there is a git command that allows a possible merge conflict between binary files.

IE: There is are two repositories and a bare remote repo which they use to share. There is a file image.png that the users the two repositories make seperate changes to and commit. They then pull the changes made and then push their changes to the remote repo. Obviously this generates a merge conflict for one of the users. But this doesn't make sense for image files, is it possible that the newest commit can be the most recent and the older commit can just be added to the history of the branch?

I'm well aware this isn't exactly how things are supposed to be done, but this is the situation I'm in so I'm wondering if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.  `git reset` just the conflicting paths to the versions you want to supersede (`git reset`*`thecommitwiththesupersededfiles`*`--`*`paths`*), commit that, then add (or reset to) the replacement (i.e. correct) versions and commit the result.  If you don't like having artificial and known-to-be-inconsistent commits on your mainline you could also make an orphan commit of *only* the superseded files (with a commit message saying what's up with them) and add that as a merge parent of the commit with the selected versions on your main branch.  Read up on `git mktree` and `git commit-tree` to see how to do that, it's actually pretty darn easy.

Comment: Is that going to make them inconsistent with the remote repo? IE: Am I going to run into consistency problems?

Comment: Nope - the conflict showed up when you were trying to merge, so you're already working on a new commit and any upstream people would have to pull that merge commit anyway.

Comment: I would have to `git checkout --theirs image.png`, commit it then `git checkout --ours image.png` both against the merge commit and then rebase to get rid of it won't I?

Comment: get rid of what?  when you get a merge conflict there is no merge commit yet.  reset stuffs the version you want in the index directly, sure you could checkout/add/commit instead but what do the extra step and pronouns get you?  ... I can't figure out where a rebase comes into the picture at all.

Comment: Ah, I thought that it did generate a merge commit, my mistake.