# Keep both binary files when there is a merge conflict in Git

Tags: git, github, binaryfiles, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

**Disclaimer**

I realize I'm using git for something it's not really designed for. But I'm *so* close to getting it to do what I want. If you have a better idea let me know...

**TL;DR**

I want to keep both binary files when there is a merge conflict. I've seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650871/get-git-to-not-merge-binary-files-but-keep-both) but I don't think it addresses my specific problem, at least, I couldn't figure out how it's actually accomplished.

**The problem**

I have hundreds of small (~4kb) binary files on a single master branch - each one is a sheet music file. Each piece of music needs to go through various stages before it's complete: formatting, adding chords, fixing lyrics, revised by person #1, revised by person #2, etc. With some batch files I can simply and easily both write and parse commit messages to generate a sort of report. Git seems to be a great solution to programatically track the status of each song. It's also very important that I keep the entire history of changes for each song and be able to look through the history easily (tortoisegit enables me to do this - right click the file and choose "git show log").

Every time a file is modified, the change is committed (i.e. each commit signifies a single changed file). So let's say I've got two songs, A and B (There are actually more than 400). There are multiple commits signifying changes in song A, and multiple commits signifying changes in song B, and the changes are spread out over the entire master branch like this:

A<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>2</sub> - B<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>3</sub> - B<sub>2</sub>

Now let's say a user makes changes to both songs A and B and pushes it up to the remote, but I am also working on songs A and B and try to pull in changes on top of mine, like this:

Remote:
A<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>2</sub> - B<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>3</sub> - B<sub>2</sub> - Their B<sub>3</sub> - Their A<sub>4</sub>
                                        ||               ||
Local:                              V               V
A<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>2</sub> - B<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>3</sub> - B<sub>2</sub> - My B<sub>3</sub>     - My A<sub>4</sub>

Classic merge conflict scenario, right?

**How can I end up with something like the following?**

Remote:
A<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>2</sub> - B<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>3</sub> - B<sub>2</sub> - Their B<sub>3</sub> - My B<sub>3</sub> - Their A<sub>4</sub> - My A<sub>4</sub>

Local:
A<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>2</sub> - B<sub>1</sub> - A<sub>3</sub> - B<sub>2</sub> - Their B<sub>3</sub> - My B<sub>3</sub> - Their A<sub>4</sub> - My A<sub>4</sub>

I've tried all the combinations and possible solutions that I could find on the web (I've learned a lot about git in the process) but can't seem to crack this one. Any help from programming wizards like yourselves is appreciated. I hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's cover some background information first.

Git commits store *snapshots of all of your files*.<sup>1</sup>  That is, each commit has a full copy of the bytes that make up each file that is stored inside that commit.  The files inside any one particular commit have names with embedded slashes, such as `path/to/file.ext`.  The copies in each commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only format.  The copies in the commits are de-duplicated (so that if you make a new commit that just re-uses some previous files, you dont actually end up with a new copy)—this is made possible by the fact that it is literally impossible to *change* the files once they're stored.  But most programs on your computer can't use the internal Git-only files, so to *use* the files, you must extract them, and that's what `git checkout` or (since Git 2.23) `git switch` does for you.

Your computer will, in general, *hold* these files in directories (or folders, if you prefer that term) so that you end up with `path` containing `to` which contains `file.ext`.  Some computers have some issues with file-name case, e.g., they cannot store both `README.TXT` *and* `readme.txt`.  But even Linux systems, which don't normally have this issue, literally cannot store both your `B` and *their* `B` under one name `B`.  Likewise, Git can't use one *name* to store two different *files* inside one commit: each file inside any given commit has to have its own unique name.

Initially, that's not a problem: you and your colleagues only have one `A` and one `B` and so on.  If only one person *changes* it, you and they pick up the updated `A` or `B`, and the updated file goes into the newer commit.  The work-tree copy, the one your computer can use, is just one copy; when you make a new commit, the new commit stores a new (or re-uses the old) frozen, Git-ified version, as appropriate.  But when you both change one of these ... well, this brings us to the merge and the merge conflict.

---

<sup>1</sup>That's the *data* part of a commit.  Commits also store *metadata*, which is information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why: your log message.  In the metadata, each commit stores the hash ID of its *parent* commit, too.  For merge commits, the commit stores the IDs (plural) of each parent.  But here, we're mostly interested in just the data.

---

#### Merging finds differences

When you run:

```
git checkout somebranch       # or git switch somebranch
git merge otherbranch
```

Git finds the *best common ancestor* commit, then runs two `git diff`s to see what files *you* changed (and how), and what files *they* changed (and how).  For text files, Git turns the "and how" part into a textual difference, then attempts to combine the two differences.  Since your files are binary, Git can't do that, and probably does not even try. :-)

Your *work-tree*, alas, can only hold *one copy* of file `B`.  But Git isn't really *using* your work-tree copy.  That's just for *you*.  Git is using *committed* copies, in the frozen format, internally.  Git stores these in what Git calls its *index*, or *staging area*, or (rarely these days) *cache*.  Normally, the index holds only one frozen-format copy of any one file.  But during a merge conflict, Git expands the index.

At this point, Git has not one, not two, but *three* active copies of file `B`.  The fact that there are these three different copies of `B`—the one that you both shared from the merge base, and then your version and their version from the two commits you're trying to merge—is why there are three copies, and the fact that there *are* three copies is how Git represents the merge conflict.

Your job, at this point, is to arrange for the index to hold only *one* copy of each file, ready to be committed.

#### You will have to rename at least one file

So you now have a merge conflict, with *three copies* of some binary file—I will keep calling it `B`—that were in the three commits, now copied into Git's index.<sup>2</sup>  Git gives you a convenient way to extract two of those three copies:

```
git checkout --ours B
```

and:

```
git checkout --theirs B
```

These two commands copy the two non-merge-base copies of the file from the index, to your work-tree.  So:

```
git checkout --ours B; mv B "My B"; git add "My B"
git checkout --theirs B; mv B "Their B"; git add "Their B"
git rm --cached B
```

will tell Git to extract your version of `B` first, which you then rename and add as `My B`.  Then you have Git extract their version of `B`, rename it, and add it.  Finally, you tell Git that the correct way to resolve the conflict between the three versions of file `B` is to remove file `B`.

The new commit you make from this will have, as part of its snapshot, the two renamed `B` copies, and no original `B` at all.

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what's in Git's index is not actually a *copy*.  It's the hash ID of the de-duplicated frozen-format *blob object* that Git uses.  But you can just think of it as a copy; it works like one.

Comment: Thank you! I've re-read your post about 5 times and it's starting to become clearer. If I've understood correctly, I may have phrased my question wrong or misunderstood my own problem. Since the commit\file "Their B" and commit\file "My B" both reference the commit/file "B2" as a parent, I'm forced to either choose one or rename files. What I think I really need is the following: can I (maybe using `rebase` or `replace`) pull in the "Their B" commit/file and change the parent pointer of the "My B" commit/file to point to "Their B" as a parent? Or maybe that doesn't work with binary files?

Comment: *All* Git has is these snapshots. There's nothing in them to say that file `B` in commit `a123456` is or is not the *same file* as file `B`, or `My B`, or whatever, in commit `b789abc`. What `git diff` does, though, is a bit sneaky. Remember that `git diff` always (well... for this purpose, always :-) ) has exactly two commits, a "left side" (usually earlier) one and a "right side" (usually later) one, and is comparing the two. [continued]

Comment: What `git diff` does is look at the file names on the left and right sides. If there's a B on both sides, it *assumes* that's "the same file" (to start with at least). But if not, well, there's a B on the left, say, but no B on the right. Is there a file name on the right that's not on the left? If so, maybe B got *renamed*. Git will then—when asked, with `--find-renames`—compare the *contents* of B-on-left to not-B-new-files-on-right. If one is "sufficiently similar", Git will declare that the file was renamed.

Comment: You can also ask Git to find "copies", with `--find-copies` and/or `--find-copies-harder`. Then it looks for whether some right-side new file is a *copy* of left side B, for instance. This depends heavily on the similarity computation, so depending on how the binary files are formed, they might or might not be similar enough to have this work out. If your Git is recent, rename finding is turned on by default; if it's old, it's off by default, but you can turn it on any time you like.

Comment: Ultimately, though, any time you have a *merge commit*, the merge commit itself has *two* parent commits. To compare the merge commit with `git diff` successfully here, you will need to run two separate `git diff`s, one against each parent. The `git show` command will do this automatically if you give it the `-m` flag ("virtually split a merge").

Comment: Thanks again! It looks like your original answer is what I really do need and want to do. However, after pulling from origin/master (creating a merge conflict), I do `git checkout --ours B` but the `git mv B` command fails with the message `fatal: not under version control, source=...`. Is it not under version control because I'm in a state of merge conflict?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why `git mv B` failed like that (that seems like the wrong error message, if nothing else -- file `B` *is* in the index, the problem is that it's still there 3 times). But the commands illustrated above use plain `mv`, not `git mv`, as we really just want to work with the in-work-tree file at this point.

Comment: Note, by the way, that ElpieKay's "rename both" answer achieves the same thing, but uses `git show` to get the two copies of file `B`.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm using a windows machine, so I need to do `move B "My B"`. `mv` is for linux. This is awesome, it's actually going to work for me! You've saved me days-worth of my time.

Comment: btw I tracked down the bogus `git mv` error message and plan to send a patch to the Git folks. It's just a case of `git mv` not understanding the internal cases for "not in index" vs "in index but not at stage 0" leading to the wrong error message. Unfortunately "git mv" can't handle conflicted files at all due to its overall design; fixing this is a bigger job...

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename one of them or both. Two files can't have the same name in the same directory. When the conflict occurs, there are 3 options.

```
# 1. rename theirs only
# 1.1 choose our version for B3
git checkout --ours B3
# 1.2 rename their version to their.B3 for example
git show FETCH_HEAD:B3 > their.B3
# 1.3 add changed files
git add B3 their.B3
# 1.4 end the merge process
git merge --continue

# 2. rename ours only
# 2.1 choose their version for B3
git checkout --theirs B3
# 1.2 rename our version to our.B3 for example
git show HEAD:B3 > our.B3
# 1.3 add changed files
git add B3 our.B3
# 1.4 end the merge process
git merge --continue

# 3. rename both
# 3.1 rename theirs to their.B3
git show FETCH_HEAD:B3 > their.B3
# 3.2 rename ours to our.B3
git show HEAD:B3 > our.B3
# 3.3 add changed files
git add our.B3 their.B3
# 3.4 remove B3
git rm B3
# 3.5 end the merge process
git merge --continue
```